# How to find the $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(2-e^{\arcsin^{2}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}\right)^{\frac{3}{x}}$

Tags: limits

im struggeling to find $$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(2-e^{\arcsin^{2}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}\right)^{\frac{3}{x}}$$

Ive tried the following:
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} ax^{bx} = \lim_{x \to x_0} e^{ax^{bx}} =  \lim_{x \to x_0} e^{bx \ln(ax)} =  e^{\lim_{x \to x_0} bx \ln(ax)}$$
wich leads me to
$$ = e^{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3\ln(2-e^{\arcsin^2(\sqrt{x})})}{x}}$$
Is this the right way to go? If yes how to get rid of the division by x?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: The most urgent task is to get rid of $\arcsin x$, because that will always cause the limit to be of form $0/0$. Do you know about its properties near $x=0$?

Comment: Okay yes, i see your point. after getting rid of the arcsin i can successfully use lHopital. Sadly im not sure about its properties near 0 or what is even meant by that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the change of variable $\sqrt{x}= \sin y$, the limit can written in the form $e^L$, where $\displaystyle L = \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{3 \ln (2-e^{y^2})}{\sin ^2 y}$. Applying L'Hopital's rule and taking out the factors that do not contribute to the indetermination , we get
$$
\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{3 \ln (2-e^{y^2})}{\sin ^2 y}= 3 \lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac{-2y e^{y^2}}{(2-e^{y^2}) \cdot 2 \cos y \sin y}=-3 \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{\sin y} = -3
$$

and so, the final answer is that your limit is $e^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider substituting $y=\arcsin(\sqrt x)$. Then $x=\sin^2y$, and $y\to0$ as $x\to0$. So the limit becomes

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(2-\exp\left(\arcsin^2\left(\sqrt x\right)\right)\right)^{\frac3x}=\lim_{y\to0}\left(2-\exp\left(y^2\right)\right)^{\frac3{\sin^2y}}$$

The log-exp manipulation you use then converts the limit to

$$\exp\left(3\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln\left(2-\exp\left(y^2\right)\right)}{\sin^2y}\right)$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+a(e^{-x}-1))^{-\frac{1}{x}}=e^a$
- $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arcsin x}{x}=1$

You can see the list of special limits in the form of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Logarithmic_and_exponential_functions_Anchor01

We have the limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}(2-e^{\arcsin^2 \sqrt{x}})^{\frac{3}{x}}$. By doing algebraic manipulation, we get: $$\begin{align} & \lim_{x\to 0}(1+(-1)(e^{\arcsin^2 \sqrt{x}}-1))^{\frac{3}{x}} \\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\Biggl((1+(-1)(e^{\arcsin^2 \sqrt{x}}-1))^{\frac{1}{\arcsin^2 \sqrt{x}}}\Biggl)^{\frac{3\arcsin^2 \sqrt{x}}{x}} \\ \end{align}$$ We know that: $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+(-1)(e^{\arcsin^2 \sqrt{x}}-1))^{\frac{1}{\arcsin^2 \sqrt {x}}}=e^{-1} \space \space \text{and} \space \space \lim_{x\to 0}3\Biggl(\frac{\arcsin \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\Biggl)^2=3 $$ This boils down to the fact that overall limit is: $$e^{-3}$$